# Record and playback using bluetooth earphone's mic & speaker in Swift using Avfoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

This below sample code is working fine ( thanks to Oskar Jonsson ).

```
 ViewController.swift
 MicToSpeakers

Created by Oskar Jönsson on 2016-09-09.
Copyright © 2016 Oskar Jönsson. All rights reserved.


import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /* when these two lines uncommented. the device was able to playback on bluetooth earbuds, however its still using the internal mic

    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                  mode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault,
                                  options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP)

    try! audioSession.setActive(true)
    */


    let input = engine.inputNode!

    engine.attach(player)

    let bus = 0
    let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: bus)

    engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputFormat)

    input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
        print(buffer)
    }



}




@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {

    do{
        try! engine.start()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


    player.play()


}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    try! engine.stop()
    player.stop()

}

}
```

But its not using the bluetooth mic & speaker when connected. so,i just want to give priority to bluetooth earbuds for recording and playing back whenever its connected, when its not the app can use phone hardware.
i played around with **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord** but none of my trials work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be my last trial worked.

```
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {

        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .allowBluetooth)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
    print(error)
    }
```

Now i can use my bluetooth earbuds for both recording and playback without internal(iphone) mic or speaker. here is full code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var engine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    do {

        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .allowBluetooth)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let input = engine.inputNode!

    engine.attach(player)

    let bus = 0
    let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: bus)

    engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputFormat)

    input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
        print(buffer)
    }



}




@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {

    do{
        try! engine.start()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


    player.play()


}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    try! engine.stop()
    player.stop()

}

}
```

*do not forget to connect IB actions(start and stop buttons) before testing it*

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 it should be:

```swift
audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .allowBluetooth)
```